# How to give a relative path to redirection operator?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, io-redirection

As you probably know, when running a python script and typing:

```
>> <file-name>
```

a file named < file-name> will be created inside the script directory, and all stdin output of this script will be directed to this file.

I want to add a feature in the script that (when using the redirection operator) will extract the file at another directory of my choice. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: The redirection operator is a shell feature. And I assume you are refering to stdout (stdin is standard input, stdout is standard output). I would bet that the shell is *not* relaying any information about the redirection operator to the script, but maybe there is a way... perhaps you should add some shell tag to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just give the full name of the directory that you'd like to redirect your output to.

```
echo hello world >> <full path of directory>/<name of output file>
```

Comment: Yes. But sometimes the path to the desired directory can be very long, so it'll be much more comfortable to have a feature that supports it.

Answer (score 0):

Files are created relative to the current directory. You can use [`os.chdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chdir) to change the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

When you run any command from a sheel and use the `>>` redirection operator, or in fact any of the standard `|`, `>` and similar ones, the one who is doing the redirection is the **shell**, not Python.

This means that the Python interpreter will not have any information about the name of the file used for the redirection. Moreover, because the file creation and file management is done by the shell, you cannot (and should not) interfere with that. I assume that you won't be allowed and the user would not expect any trickery on that.

If you want to atune the behaviour of your application depending on the fact that the output is being redirected, take a look at `sys.stdout.isatty()` method, which will return `True` if the script has been called from an interactive tty. When the output is redirected, it will return `False`. However, note that there are a handful of scenarios where `isatty()` will return false but the reason won't be a redirection operator (like pipe operator, or some third script including a call to your script).

Of course, you could avoid the redirection operator and use some argument for your script. Without any further information, I would advise to do so, that way you will have complete control on the behaviour and you could document it (instead of relying of a shell thing, which may or may not be portable and flexible).